# Python create image with continous input

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing

I have a code where an image got converted to B/W.
Now I want to build a new image in reference to the original image.

The output of the original image are the X-/Y-coordinates and "1" and "0" for Black and White.

The new image will receive these information but not chronologically.
Therefore it must check and provide a negative output if it already has received information about a specific coordinate so that double entries can be avoided.

I haven´t found many similar examples to this; only some examples that are going in the about direction.

Does anyone have an idea how to realize that?

UPDATE:

I built the code which converts a pixel from a white image black, if the reference pixel from the original image is black (Otherwise it leaves it white).

Furthermore the used coordinate is entered into a list and checked if used.
However, this part is not working properly.
Although the coordinate [10, 10] has been used in the loop before, the code displays `Coordinate not in the system`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy

white = cv2.imread('white.jpg') #loading white image
white = cv2.resize(white,(640,480)) #adjusting it to the size of the original image


y = 0 #for testing purposes the white image gets blackened manually
x = 0
j = 0

while j < 50:
    content = numpy.zeros((200, 2)) #creating a list with 200 entries, every entry contains 2 values
    content = ([x, y]) #adding two values to the list

    if condition[y, x] = 1: #condition = 1 means that in the reference picture at this coordinate the pixel is black
        white[y,x] = 0 #"0" creates a black pixel at the specified coordinate on the white image
    x += 5
    y += 5
    j += 1

x = 10 #taking a value which already has been used 
y = 10

try:
    b = content.index([x, y]) #check if coordinate is in the list
except ValueError:
    print("Coordinate not in the system")
else:
    print("Coordinate already in the system")


i = 0

while i < 100:

    cv2.imshow('Bild', white) #displays the image
    if cv2. waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: I can't read python, and I don't understand what you are trying to do, but if you do `pixel=255-pixel` it will invert the pixel, making `0` into `255` and `255` into `0`.

Comment: The inverting of the pixels is already working properly. I want to write the coordinates of the inverted pixels into a list and check if the coordinate is already inserted into the list. But thanks for your help anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but I was able to solve it without any complex lists or arrays.
Might not be the most elegant way but at least it is working!

I created a second white picture (=reference) which is getting compared if the coordinate has already been used or not.
If the coordinate has not been used, it will create a black pixel.
The next time it is checking this coordinate it will find a black pixel and therefore know that it has been used.

In the end the white image will contain 49 black pixels (because the position [10, 10] has already been used and will not become painted).

```
import cv2
import numpy

white = cv2.imread('C:\white.jpg') #loading white image
reference = cv2.imread('C:\white.jpg') #loading white image
white = cv2.resize(white,(640,480)) #adjusting it to the size of the original image
reference = cv2.resize(white,(640,480)) #adjusting it to the size of the original image

y = 0 #for testing purposes the white image gets blackened manually
x = 0
j = 0

reference[10,10] = 0


while j < 50:

    if [255,255,255] in reference[y,x]:
        reference[y,x] = 0 #"0" creates a black pixel at the specified coordinate on the reference image
        white[y,x] = 0 #"0" creates a black pixel at the specified coordinate on the white image
        print("Coordinate not in system")
    else:
        print("coordinate already in system")
    x += 5
    y += 5
    j += 1


i = 0

while i < 100:

    cv2.imshow('image copy', white) #displays the image
    if cv2. waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```